# How to crop AI (PDF embedded) to PNG using Ghostscript?

Tags: image, png, ghostscript

I've read a number of post and tried to follow but it's not working.

Using GS (gsdll32.dll) with the following arguments:

Info from bbox

> %%BoundingBox: 33 244 577 546 %%HiResBoundingBox: 33.611976 244.201633
>   576.009896 545.351819
>
> render and crop AI2PNG
>   -P-
>   -dNOPAUSE
>   -dBATCH
>   -dSAFER
>   -q
>   -IC:/Program Files (x86)/Gerber Scientific Products/OMEGA 6.50/Software/gs/fonts;C:/Program Files (x86)/Gerber Scientific Products/OMEGA 6.50/Software/gs/lib;C:/Program Files (x86)/Gerber
>   Scientific Products/OMEGA 6.50/Software/gs/resource
>   -sDEVICE=pngalpha
>   -g544x302
>   -c <> setpagedevice
>   -sOutputFile=E:/Images/AI from PLM/captain-america [Converted].png E:/Images/AI from PLM/captain-america [Converted].ai

Without any cropping logic I get the image on an 8.5 x 11, with cropping(above commands) the objects are translated mostly off the top of the page and do not seem to move to the left.

The size of the result image is correct.

Does anyone see anything wrong?

Thanks

Comment: AI2PNG
-P-
-dNOPAUSE
-dBATCH
-dSAFER
-q
-IC:/Program Files (x86)/Gerber Scientific Products/OMEGA 6.50/Software/gs/fonts;C:/Program Files (x86)/Gerber Scientific Products/OMEGA 6.50/Software/gs/lib;C:/Program Files (x86)/Gerber Scientific Products/OMEGA 6.50/Software/gs/resource
-sDEVICE=pngalpha
-g544x302
-sOutputFile=E:/Images/AI from PLM/captain-america [Converted].png
E:/Images/AI from PLM/captain-america [Converted].ai
-c
<</Install { -33 -244 translate }>> setpagedevice

Answer (score 0):

You've put the /Install **after** the input file, that means it will be executed after the input file is complete. Which means it takes effect after the input is completely processed, which is too late to have nay effect.

Order of switches, and particularly order of input, is important in Ghostscript.

That's assuming that 'AI2PNG' is a synonym for Ghostscript.

Comment: AI2PNG
-P-
-dNOPAUSE
-dBATCH
-dSAFER
-q
-IC:/Program Files (x86)/Gerber Scientific Products/OMEGA 6.50/Software/gs/fonts;C:/Program Files (x86)/Gerber Scientific Products/OMEGA 6.50/Software/gs/lib;C:/Program Files (x86)/Gerber Scientific Products/OMEGA 6.50/Software/gs/resource
-sDEVICE=pngalpha
-r72
-sOutputFile=E:/Images/AI from PLM/captain-america [Converted].png
-g544x302
-c
<</Install { -33 -244 translate }>> setpagedevice
-fE:/Images/AI from PLM/captain-america [Converted].ai

Comment: Are you saying this still doesn't work ? If so what is 'AI2PNG' (because it isn't Ghostscript which should be called gs or gswinxx), if its a renamed Ghostscript, what version is it ? If you built it yourself then I'd recommend trying the current version available from the ghostscript.com website. You should also strive to reduce the command line, especially getting rid of all the extra includes in the -I switch, in case you have outdated/modified resource files. Realistically, if you expect help you are going to have to post an example we can try. This is like hunting black cats in cellars

Comment: Also, I suspect you may find that putting quotes round the content between -c and -f might help. Eg -c "<</Install { -33 -244 translate }>> setpagedevice" -f A space after the -f before the input filename wouldn't go amiss either. Are you reading the back channel ? It seems to me there should be errors or at the least more information being returned.